# problem with append text with style in richtextfx

Tags: javafx, text-styling, richtextfx

i want to append specific text with style in `StyleClassedTextArea` in `richtextfx` using method `append(String text, String sytleClass)` but there was a problem

```
StyleClassTextArea textarea=new StyleClassedTextArea();
textarea.appendText("no-style");
textarea.append("with-style","error");
textarea.appendText("no-style");
```

i think the output would be (for the style i used bold text)

> no-style **with-style** no-style

but the actual output is

> no-style **with-style no style**

It apply style to all text that added later
so, what is the solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I issued this in rihtextfx github page
see this issue for more details [richtextfx issue-938](https://github.com/FXMisc/RichTextFX/issues/938)